# Как сохранить страницы в django-cms после запуска django на docker

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Добрый день! Использую сайт на django, который разворачивается на докере. Поставил на него django-cms 3.3.2. После запуска докера django-cms работает, но нет ни одной страницы. Как сделать, что после каждого запуска контейнера докера сохранялись страницы  django-cms?

Comment: Хранить базу данных за пределами ФС докера, не?

Comment: А возможно сделать чтобы, модели cms были на одно БД, а основные модели на другой?